# Div positioning - how to put one below others

Tags: html, css, css-float

The DIV positioning is driving me crazy so I hope someone here can help me.

I have 4 div inside a big one.
The yellow stays in left - OK

The red stays in right - OK

The blue stays in right but the margin should be related to the screen, not the red div.. How to fix that?

The pink stays in right but want to put below the blue and red. How to do that?

Any help would be welcome!

I have this:
[image]

And want this:
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>


#divtop {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;

}

#divtop #div1 { /* yellow */
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    margin-left: 50px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#FF0;
}

#divtop #div2 {
    float:right;    
    position:relative;  
    margin-right:50px;  
    width:30px;
    background-color:#F00; /* red */
}

#divtop #div3 {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:100px;     
    width:60px;
    background-color:#00F; /* blue */
}

#divtop #div4 {
    float:right;    
    position:relative;  
    width:150px;    
    margin-right:50px;  
    margin-top:40px;        
    background-color:#F0F;  /* pink */

}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="divtop"><!-- DIV TOP --><!-- black -->

<div id="div1"><!-- yellow -->
&nbsp;
</div>

<div id="div2"><!-- red -->
&nbsp;
</div>

<div id="div3"><!-- blue -->
&nbsp;
</div>

<div id="div4"><!-- pink -->
&nbsp;
</div>

</div><!-- END DIV TOP -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post a image to explain what you expect.

Comment: or else a fiddle..please..

Comment: I have uploaded some pics... hope someone help me

Comment: Not a solution but [this](http://blog.niranjanborawake.in/2014/01/css-position-property.html) might help you writing your own..

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you.

```css
#divtop {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    z-index: 0;
  padding:0px 50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;

}

#divtop #div1 { /* yellow */
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#FF0;
}

#divtop #div2 {
    float:right;    
    margin-right:50px;  
    width:30px;
    background-color:#F00; /* red */
}

#divtop #div3 {
    float:right;
    width:60px;
    background-color:#00F; /* blue */
}

#divtop #div4 {
    float:right;    
    position:relative;  
    width:150px;    
    margin-top:40px;        
    background-color:#F0F;  /* pink */
  clear:both;

}
```

```html
<div id="divtop"><!-- DIV TOP --><!-- black -->

<div id="div1"><!-- yellow -->&nbsp; </div>

<div id="div3"><!-- blue --> &nbsp;</div>
<div id="div2"><!-- red -->&nbsp; </div>

<div id="div4"><!-- pink -->
&nbsp;
</div>

</div><!-- END DIV TOP -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to make 2 parent divs as 1 for left and 1 for right float.so it would be easy to manage with floats. **DEMO:**    **http://jsfiddle.net/arw17hff/**

```
<div id="divtop"><!-- DIV TOP --><!-- black -->
<div class="left">
<div id="div1"><!-- yellow -->
&nbsp;
</div>
 </div>
<div class="right">
<div id="div2"><!-- red -->
&nbsp;
</div>  
<div id="div3"><!-- blue -->
&nbsp;
</div>   
<div id="div4"><!-- pink -->
&nbsp;
</div>      
    </div>   
</div><!-- END DIV TOP -->
```

---

```
#divtop {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;

}

#divtop #div1 { /* yellow */
    position: relative; 
    margin-left: 50px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#FF0;
}

#divtop #div2 {
    float:right;    
    position:relative;  
    margin-right:50px;  
    width:30px;
    background-color:#F00; /* red */
}

#divtop #div3 {
    position:relative;
    margin-right:100px;     
    width:60px;
    background-color:#00F; /* blue */
}

#divtop #div4 {
    float:right;    
    position:relative;  
    width:150px;    
    margin-right:50px;  
    margin-top:40px;        
    background-color:#F0F;  /* pink */

}
.left{float:left}
.right{float:right}
```

Answer (score 0):

So just something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vmz4fLhe/)? I just added the following rule to #divtop #div4

```
clear:both;
```

Answer (score 0):

please try adding a new div element div5 as shown below.
    
    
    
    
    Untitled Document

```
#divtop {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;

}

#divtop #div1 { /* yellow */
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    margin-left: 50px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#FF0;
}

#divtop #div2 {
    float:right;    
    position:relative;  
    margin-right:50px;  
    width:30px;
    background-color:#F00; /* red */
}

#divtop #div3 {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:100px;     
    width:60px;
    background-color:#00F; /* blue */
}

#divtop #div4 {    
    position:relative;  
    width:150px;    
    margin-right:50px;  
    margin-top:40px;        
    background-color:#F0F;  /* pink */

}
#divtop #div5 {/* to bind div2,div3,div4 together */
    float:right;    
    position:relative;  
    width:auto;    
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="divtop"><!-- DIV TOP --><!-- black -->

<div id="div1"><!-- yellow -->
&nbsp;
</div>
<div id="div5">
<div id="div2"><!-- red -->
&nbsp;
</div>

<div id="div3"><!-- blue -->
&nbsp;
</div>

<div id="div4"><!-- pink -->
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- END DIV TOP -->


</body>
</html>
```